# GAE Error | Server Encountered an Error and couldn't complete your request. Please try again after 30 seconds

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, webapp2

We have an app running on Google App Engine with Python 2.7 runtime which can be assessed using Google Login, implemented using [users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/users/) endpoint.

We are getting an error "Server Encountered an Error and couldn't complete your request. Please try again after 30 seconds" whenever user tries to open the web app.. The error is thworn on App Engine side, since the 500 error happens on that line where this call is made 'GET https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin'. 
[image]

This happens for both mobile(majorly) and web.  It shows the same error when we try after the specified time.

However when we clear the browser cookies, cache, history etc etc it starts working. Not sure why. But we cannot users to clear all such stuffs all time as they might loose the information that they browsed.

We tried various cases for login(multiple login, single login, incognito mode) but couldn't figure the root cause of the problem.

Have anyone faced such issues before? If yes please share how you solved it.

Comment: Is there a traceback in the App Engine logs?

Comment: no :( we couldn't find anything on appengine logs.